# SQL Server Insert trigger inserting more than once

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-trigger

My  trigger is for some reason inserting 4 times, and the last one is only being grouped. Basically what I want to do is when information is inserted into my table `tbl_delete_Panel` I want to group this data and insert the grouping into `tbl_delete_panel_Orderin`.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE Trigger[dbo].[deletePanelSQL]
ON [dbo].[tbl_delete_Panel]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
     /* Insert Summed Quantity for each stud or track into tbl_delete_panel for deletion. tbl_delete_panel trigger will be triggered */
    INSERT INTO tbl_delete_panel_Orderin (Part_Name, OrderID, SumOfQTY)
       SELECT 
           tbl_delete_panel.Part_Name, tbl_delete_panel.OrderID, 
           Sum(tbl_delete_panel.QTY) AS SumOfQTY
       FROM 
           tbl_delete_panel
       GROUP BY 
           tbl_delete_panel.Part_Name, tbl_delete_panel.OrderID;
END;
```

Comment: You keep inserting the complete rows from `tbl_delete_panel`, everytime this trigger is called. What you **should do** is look at the `Inserted` pseudo table which *can and will contain* multiple rows - and insert **those rows** (that were newly inserted by the statement that triggered the trigger) - not the **whole table** every time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you keep inserting the **complete set of rows** from the `tbl_delete_panel`, every time this trigger is fired.

What you **should do instead** is look at the `Inserted` pseudo table which **can and will contain multiple rows** (so you need to handle that situation, with a nice, proper **set-based approach** - no cursor, no while loops!) - and insert those rows (that were newly inserted by the statement that caused the trigger to fire) - not the whole table every time !

Try something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE Trigger[dbo].[deletePanelSQL]
ON [dbo].[tbl_delete_Panel]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
     /* Insert summed quantity for each stud or track into tbl_delete_panel for deletion. tbl_delete_panel trigger will be triggered */
    INSERT INTO tbl_delete_panel_Orderin (Part_Name, OrderID, SumOfQTY)
       SELECT 
           Part_Name, OrderID, 
           Sum(QTY) AS SumOfQTY
       FROM 
           Inserted i
       GROUP BY 
           Part_Name, OrderID;
END;
```